# FileCreateShortcut behaves weird

Tags: autohotkey, shortcut-file

I am using

```
FileCreateShortcut, %A_WorkingDir%\some.exe, %A_Desktop%\Some.lnk
```

to create the shortcut. But if desktop contains a folder named "Some" for some reason it decides to create a shortcut for it rather than a shortcut for the target specified. Also, it quite hard to delete these shortcuts. If it deleted it also deletes the folder. Why is that happening and how to avoid it?

I am using Windows 10 if that is helpful. I have tried running the script as admin, it doesn't make any difference. Also, It works fine and creates a shortcut as long as the folder with the same name on the desktop doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to recreate the exact situation with the same names and locations, but it ran successfully. It created a separate link from an existing folder with the same name. Deleting the shortcut had no issues and left the folder there. I also tried running it with an invalid .exe path, but it still ran successfully and had similar behavior to what I had previously mentioned.

While I don't know why this is happening to you, I would recommend ensuring that you're running the latest Windows 10 updates (and there are no pending updates, waiting for a restart) and the latest version of AutoHotkey.

In my case, I'm running Win10 version 1903, build 18362.145 and AutoHotkey v1.1.30.03.

Comment: It works with an invalid path to target as well for me as long desktop doesn't contain a folder with the same name. I am running Win10 version 1809 build 17763.504 and AutoHotkey v1.1.30.03. The only other thing is that Windows running on Parallels so my desktop path looks like «\\Mac\Home\Desktop» and target path looks like «C:\Program Files\Some\some.exe». I made so it checks for the existence of that folder but that only a temporary fix.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I wonder if specifying the full path instead of using `A_Desktop` fixes it.

Comment: I tried it on a different machine running purely win10 and there were no problems. Probably just a bug caused by an exotic directory of the desktop.

Comment: I agree. That seems the most likely. It may be worth reporting that on the forums as a possible bug.